# laravel elequent model attribute does gives method not found in blade file where as works fine in the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My laravel version is 5.6.23
Here is my model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;    
    public function getIsBusinessAttribute(){
        return $this->business == 0;
    }
}
```

In a controller when I call

```
Auth::User()->isBusiness
```

it returns true

But when I try the same code in the blade file

```
@if(Auth::User()->isBusiness)
```

it gives this error

### Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isBusiness does not exist

I have tried every option like

```
@if(Auth::User()->is_business)
@if(Auth::User()->IsBusiness)
```

but nothing works in the blade file?

Comment: try to deal with it as method  @if(Auth::User()->is_business())

Comment: Pass the variable to the blade via the controller.

Comment: @ali that definitly does not work because it is not a method it is an attribute

Comment: @S.Dev Thanks but then whats the use of Auth::User() if I have to pass it through the controller

Comment: add appending attribute in model

Comment: protected $appends = ['is_business'];

Comment: Please add `{{ dd(Auth::User()) }}` to your view and post the result.

Comment: $appends only helps when the model gets cast to an array or to json.  Is there any reason you are using Auth::User() instead of Auth::user() as the examples in documentation do?  Also, for sure do all your testing with snake case "is_business", "isBusiness" certainly will not work.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Comment: I only have 5.5 but cannot replicate your issue.  Works fine in both controller and view (and without snake case).  What I find odd is that this message is from query builder, and not from your model.  Obviously it has been pointed out that user should be in lower case, but again, worked for me in either case.